# What is the purpose of these roof joists/braces in old house can they be removed

Tags: joists, roofing

I am working with builder to replace the ceiling in the loft of my 200 year old house.

The old ceiling has been taken down and we are going to put joists between rafters for the new ceiling, attaching to the rafter just above the existing purlins.

In the loft room two purlins run down each side of the room each purlins runs from the gable wall to a central structure that supports the other end. But there also two additional braces that traverse the room and run under the two northern purlins and the builder says it is okay to remove since when we add the two new celing joists these will tie pairs of rafters together and provide further support, but Im not so sure. Each brace is notched out to run under the purlin  and bolted to the purlin from the bottom on one side and then attched to the rafter on the other side. So one brace is attached to the left purlin and one to the right purlin.

I know purlins mainly support the rafters (and it turn is supported by load bearing walls), but since each has a v notch under each purlin it seems it is intended to somehow support the purlin rather than tie the rafter to the purlin. Since the main central brace that supports the central structure  also has these vnotches and this is clearly intended to support the purlin.

Note I use the word **brace** and **vnotch** for the want of a better word.

[image: All 3 braces]
All 3 braces (furthest two be removed)

[image: brace 1 left]
brace 1 left side

[image: brace 1 right]
brace 1 right side

[image: brace 2 left]
brace 2 left side

[image: brace 2 right]
brace 2 right side

Comment: Looks to me like they stop the roof from collapsing down and pushing the walls apart. They're probably under tension to prevent the ends from spreading outwards.

Answer (score 3):

Those at least appear to be collar ties, a very important part of the roof system. Do not remove them. The squarish looking beam running perpendicular to the rafters appears to be a strong back or purlin. It helps unify the rafters so if one takes a load, it is distributed over many. Also an important component, they are held in place by the collar ties. everything would need to be rebuilt with a design by a structural engineer before any of this can be removed.

Comment: thx, now we are going to put new ceiling joists above the purlins connecting each paitr of rafters (via coach bolts), so in effect adding a series of collar ties. But my concern is that these are above the purlin whereas the existing ones are below the purlin so are they supporting the purlin in some way as well, or acting as some kind ogf secondary protection in case the support at one end of purlin fails in some way.

Comment: Lee Sam may need to chime in to, but I see both parts are integral, but the collar ties are the primary part. The placement of the collar ties are important too, as in where along the rafter they set. They may be able to be repositioned as you are suggesting but then the rafter dimensions, spacing and snow loads are needed to be calculated. That's why the engineer.